# How to highlight a button that is clicked in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

Highlight, just like when you hover over to the button, its being highlighted. But how do you retain the highlight when you have clicked the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight a button you have to use two buttons.

1. a button with red in color (example-red_button)
2. a button with faded red in color(example-faded_red_button,visible as false)

Place one above the other.

On the mouse down event of the red_button:

```
red_button.sendtoback
faded_red_button.bringtofront
faded_redb_button.visible=true
```

On the mouse up event of the red_button:

```
faded_red_button.sendtoback
red_button.bringtofront
red_button.visible=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why do you need this behaviour, but maybe you could use another control instead of Button. **You could use CheckBox, with the appearance of a button**. You can change this appearance in the properties window of the checkbox.

If you don't want to use this option, just let me know :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not much of a functional spec.  When it is supposed to turn off?  Anyhoo, use a CheckBox, set Appearance = Button, AutoSize = False, TextAlign = MiddleCenter.

Answer (score 1):

If this is WPF or Silverlight, you can simply re-template the [Button control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28VS.95%29.aspx), and change the "Normal" state to match the "MouseOver" state.  Not sure what you're using though?